# I am trying to set up aDHCP server in a VLAN for practical of networking with Linux

Tags: vlan, ip, ipv4, subnet, ip-address

I am a Linux user requesting advice about setting up a DHCP with a VLAN based on offices on one floor for the practical purpose.

Is this good enough for implementing a VLAN structure with a DHCP server using these pool of addresses?

[image]

Comment: The last two lines have invalid IPv4 addresses. You should read and understand [this two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) if you are trying to do IPv4 addressing. In any case, the question is really too broad, and we would need more information, but we cannot design this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have will not work because half of the addresses you have are not valid IPv4 addresses. The `192.168.300.1`, `192.168.300.150`, `192.168.400.1`, and `192.168.400.150` addresses are all invalid IPv4 addresses.

You should really learn IPv4 addressing before trying to configure something like this.

Comment: Ah crap! An easy error I missed out on. Thanks Ron.

I shall make the addressing under 255 than over.